# What settings are needed to use GraalVM with sbt in Intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, graalvm

I'm want to use graalvm in Intellij with my Scala project and sbt.
In my build.sbt I set this:

```
scalacOptions += "-target:1.8.0"
```

I have my graalvm in my path, and see this when I run "java -version":

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_202"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-20190206132754.buildslave.jdk8u-src-tar--b08)
OpenJDK GraalVM CE 1.0.0-rc16 (build 25.202-b08-jvmci-0.59, mixed mode)
```

So I also tried "1.8.0_202".  Neither sbt nor Intellij liked any of these settings.

What is needed to make this work?